# How can we access an object type(not table of objects) in Oracle TABLE function?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, object-type, table-functions

How can we access an object type(not table of objects) in TABLE function ?

The table function works on a collection of objects, but I have a need to access a single row using TABLE function.

I get the error "ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item" when I try to use TABLE function with an object type instead of collection of object types.

The workaround that I use is to create a table type collection on this object and place the row in the first index, and then use the table type in the function. Any other simple solutions ?

I need to query the object as if it is a row in a table.This is to have a common code base in my application to support two different use cases.

With a common code base, I can use the same SELECT query to query the records either from an actual table or from a single-row object using TABLE function. Only the FROM clause of the Dynamic SQL changes.

```
CASE 1: 
Querying a physical table

v_select := 'SELECT a,b,c,d '
v_from   := '  FROM ' || v_actual_table 
v_where  := '<where_predicate>

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_select || v_from  || v_where;


CASE 2:
Querying a row object using TABLE function. The row object is coming from Oracle AQ channel in the form of messages.

v_select := 'SELECT a,b,c,d '
v_from   := '  FROM TABLE(:1)' 
v_where  := '<where_predicate>

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_select || v_from  || v_where USING v_table_type;
```

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Why do you want to access a single object with a `table()` function? Please explain what you're doing and why, including object/type and table definitions and your current code. It's hard to offer a solution for something that doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I have edited my post to include some sample code and description of my requirement. Thanks!